Ubuntu 22.04 - BCM4377b recognising surrounding networks but unable to connect
I ran into a problem with my 2xThunderbolt 3, 2020 MacBook Pro (Intel) trying to dual boot Ubuntu from an external drive. Booting works fine, and the OS works as expected. The battery can be read, the desktop is responsive, etc., however, I've run into a major networking problem. When scanning for networks via Settings or the control center in the top right, all networks appear, with signal visible, and correct, however when inputting the correct password for the network, it gets stuck. It's just spinning, acting as if it is doing something. Then, after failing, all the visible networks disappear, and scanning no longer works.
The WiFi card is the "BCM4377b" (14e4:4480 rev 04)
I have installed apple-firmware_14.7.1-1_all.deb, and install.sh (install.sh fails to run on Ubuntu, that was on an Arch install with the exact same issue, but that was booting from the Arch .iso live environment. The logs from which via journalctl were the exact same as provided by this article.
Dec 24 22:34:19 hostname kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Dec 24 22:34:19 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie for chip BCM4377/4
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,tahiti-SPPR-m-3.1-X0.bin failed with error -2
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,tahiti-SPPR-m-3.1.bin failed with error -2
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,tahiti-SPPR-m.bin failed with error -2
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,tahiti-SPPR.bin failed with error -2
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4377b3-pcie.apple,tahiti-X0.bin failed with error -2
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_txcap_blob: TxCap blob found, loading
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4377/4 wl0: Jul 16 2021 18:25:13 version 16.20.328.0.3.6.105 FWID 01-30be2b3a
Dec 24 22:34:20 hostname kernel: brcmfmac 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0f0: renamed from wlan0

Please leave a comment if any more logs are needed.

Double click on that deb file you downloaded, then reboot

Thank you for the comment, and the edit. Turns out, as it does, leaving it overnight "fixed" it. Network would connect, and would work at the full advertised 500mbps (cap of my router per device). However, when either turning Bluetooth on, or leaving it for too long?, it would disconnect and would no longer show any available networks, and would bug the menu out.
Solution? Reinstalling Ubuntu twice (first time messed with the bootloader?), and then installing the .deb with dpkg -i apple-firmware.deb
Also be warned, do not install the t2-kernel, it seems to kill all of this.

After testing (and leaving for a period of time) the WiFi will disconnect and cause the card to no longer be able to scan for networks, with the only solution to be a restart. Has anyone had this problem?

Does iwconfig show power management on?
